# Transfer files between partitions?

Tags: bootcamp, partition, windows, filesystem, ntfs

After using Boot Camp to install Windows on my Mac, is there any way to transfer files between the two partitions as each is only read only to the other.

This is mainly because I have run out of space on one partition and was wondering if I was able to download files to my main Mac partition which will be used on my windows side, or is the formatting incorrect for this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use some third party tools like Paragon-NTFS. It installs a driver on the Mac side that reads the NTFS partition of your Windows side. Some years ago I used the free "FUSE" drivers, but it seems to me, the development has stopped.

http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/index.html

Another solution would be to use a USB thumb drive, which is FAT-formatted as a transfer volume. Both sides can read and write on that.